# codeigniter not loading application/core files

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, autoload

Got a problem with codeigniter with exteding the core. I build a website local and it workst perfect. Even when checking out on new machine or diferent php version ( tested on 5.3 and 5.2 ) it works normal. But when i upload it to my server it doesnt load the files in application/core. I get the error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'LEAN_Controller' not found in /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/controllers/wachtlijsten/overzicht.php on line 3
```

When i ouput the loaded files like so:

```
print_r(get_included_files());
```

i get these results:
localhost:

```
Array ( [0] => C:\wamp\www\website\index.php [1] =>    
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\CodeIgniter.php [2] =>    
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Common.php [3] =>    
C:\wamp\www\website\application\config\constants.php [4] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Benchmark.php [5] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\application\config\config.php [6] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Hooks.php [7] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Config.php [8] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\libraries\Log.php [9] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Utf8.php [10] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\URI.php [11] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Router.php [12] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\application\config\routes.php [13] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Output.php [14] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\application\config\mimes.php [15] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Security.php [16] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Input.php [17] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Lang.php [18] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\system\core\Controller.php [19] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\application\core\lean_controller.php [20] =>     
C:\wamp\www\website\application\controllers\wachtlijsten\overzicht.php )
```

server:

```
Array ( [0] => /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/index.php [1] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/CodeIgniter.php [2] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Common.php [3] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/config/constants.php [4] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Benchmark.php [5] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/config/config.php [6] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Hooks.php [7] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Config.php [8] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/libraries/Log.php [9] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Utf8.php [10] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/URI.php [11] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Router.php [12] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/config/routes.php [13] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Output.php [14] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/config/mimes.php [15] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Security.php [16] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Input.php [17] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Lang.php [18] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/system/core/Controller.php [19] =>
 /var/www/vhosts/website/subdomains/w8systeem/httpdocs/application/controllers/wachtlijsten/overzicht.php )
```

I'm out of ideas. Dont know where to search further..

Answer (score 1):

By default, CodeIgniter only loads core files that start with 'CI_', to change this, as yours starts with 'LEAN_', you need to change the following line in **config/config.php**:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'CI_';
```

to

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'LEAN_';
```

Comment: Sounds silly but you've double checked that the file is uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code igniter version.  I had a similar issue today where core mods weren't being picked up (< 2.0).  I'm in the middle of migrating at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

C:\wamp\www\website\application\core\lean_controller.php

should be

C:\wamp\www\website\application\core\LEAN_Controller.php

Linux is case sensitive, windows is not